# Moving from one view controller to another view controller is not working in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, viewcontroller

Find my code I have checked everything is correct and tried all the possible solutions that are available here but no use. The same code worked for me in another view controller for moving to another view controller.

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // handle tap events
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
    let nextViewControllerObj = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "symptomsView") as! SymptomsViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewControllerObj, animated: true)

}
```

Comment: what problem you are facing

Comment: @jarin put a breakpoint at self.navigationController and check it shouldn't be nil.

Comment: @ Rahul Symptoms view controller is not opening when I clicked the collection view cell

Comment: Ok Jaiswal I ll check it

Comment: Its nil Jaiswal gertting log self.navigationController is nil.

Answer (score 2):

There are following possibilities that prevent to move one view controller to another view controller.

> You are using `self.storyboard?` (an optional), so it might possible that `self.storyboard` is `nil` and you won't get the view controller to move on.

- So the solution is that you need to make sure that self.storyboard is not `nil`. for eg.

  ```
  guard let mainStoryboard = self.storyboard {
    print("Storyboard is nil.")
    return
  }

  //here you can use like...
  let nextViewControllerObj = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "symptomsView") as! SymptomsViewController
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewControllerObj, animated: true)
  ```

> You are pushing view controller on navigation stack by using `self.navigationController?` (an optional). In this case it possible that navigation bar is `nil` so you ,might have the view controller but you don't have the navigation to push onto.

- The solution is that you need to make sure that there navigation controller to push the view controller. for eg.

  ```
  guard let navController = self.navigationController {
    print("self.navigationController is nil.")
    return
  }

  //here you can use like...
  let nextViewControllerObj = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "symptomsView") as! SymptomsViewController
  navController.pushViewController(nextViewControllerObj, animated: true)
  ```

So by combining both the solution you can use like...

```
    guard let mainStoryboard = self.storyboard {
      print("self.storyboard is nil.")
      return
    }

    guard let navController = self.navigationController {
      print("self.navigationController is nil.")
      return
    }

   let nextViewControllerObj = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "symptomsView") as! SymptomsViewController
   navController.pushViewController(nextViewControllerObj, animated: true)
```

So if any of this object is `nil`, you will get a message in console.

Hope this will help you:)

Comment: self.navigationController is nil.
Getting log like this what should I do to correct this.

Comment: it means there is navigation controller is not present. you need to create a navigation controller object and then you can present screen using navigation controller.

Comment: I am not using navigationcontroller so I have to use present controller instead of push. Thanks dude

Comment: Yes, you can create an object of navigation controller with root view controller and present it.

Comment: okay mahendran thanks